# CSS change NON sibling or child element property on hover

Tags: html, css

I want to know if there's ability to change CSS of element that is not direct child or sibling of element hovered.

```
<style>

   .one:hover .two {
      color:red;
   }

</style>

<div>
   <div class="one">
      111    
   </div>
</div>

<div class="two">
   222
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hgd0drky/

Comment: Do you want to set the properties of two elements on hover of one? Without any child or parent relationship?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with CSS only. You will need some javascript

Comment: This question has been asked a number of times, please search harder. The only alternative is the `label for=` hack.

Comment: Gr8 i'll check this out. English not my first language so sometimes coming up with good search query is not easy.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you add a parent element to both and make them have Child / Sibling relationship it is not possible purely based on CSS.

You will need javascript, however to demonstrate how easy this can be, I shall make up CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/hgd0drky/1/

```
<div class="one">
   <div >
      111
   </div>

    <div class="two">
      222
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.one:hover div {color:red;}
.one:hover .two {color:red;}
```

Which is just an extension of your code.

Comment: Heh question was if it can work with that particular sequence of div's i know how to make it work regular way...

Comment: I do understand your question and the answer is that its not possible without Javascript